# Shortening Javascript for repeated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently made some widgets where hovering on entire div adds classes to the other divs within same parent div.

I used the following JavaScript (using jQuery) to do that however I have 4 similar main divs so I just repeated the JS 4 times (with slight changes in class names).

Is there any way to rewrite the JS to make it more compact as it contains a lot of repeats?

P.S. If not already obvious, I'm a JS noob. ;)

```js
$('.dts-fb-hover').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb1').find('.dts-fb-bzh,.dts-fb-text,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbw-bz1').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb1').find('.dts-fb-bzh,.dts-fb-text,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbw-bz1').removeClass('hover');
});

$('.dts-fb-hover').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb2').find('.dts-fb-bzh,.dts-fb-text,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbn-bz1').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb2').find('.dts-fb-bzh,.dts-fb-text,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbn-bz1').removeClass('hover');
});

$('.dts-fb-hover').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb3').find('.dts-fb-bzh,.dts-fb-text,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbn-bz1').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb3').find('.dts-fb-bzh,.dts-fb-text,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbn-bz1').removeClass('hover');
});

$('.dts-fb-hover').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb4').find('.dts-fb-bzh,#dts-fb-cd-wrap,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbw-bz1').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb4').find('.dts-fb-bzh,#dts-fb-cd-wrap,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbw-bz1').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
#dts-fb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.dts-fb-trap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #000000;
}

.dts-fb-trap.hover {
  color: #bf0000;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #bcbcbc;
}

.dts-fb-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.dts-fb-text.hover {
  transform: scale(1.05) translateY(-50%);
}

.dts-fb-hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

.dts-fb-ha {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dts-fb-ha.hover {
  right: 10px;
}

.dts-fb1,
.dts-fb2,
.dts-fb3,
.dts-fb4 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dts-fbw-bz1,
.dts-fbn-bz1 {
  background-color: #202020;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.dts-fbw-bz1.hover,
.dts-fbn-bz1.hover {
  background-color: #909090;
}

.dts-fb-bzh.hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #404040;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dts-fb">
  <div class="dts-fb1">
    <div class="dts-fb-trap"> Title </div>
    <h3 class="dts-fb-text">Some content here..</h3>
    <div class="dts-fbw-bz1"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-bzh"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-ha"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dts-fb-hover"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="dts-fb2">
    <div class="dts-fb-trap">
      <h3 class="dts-fb-trap-title">Title2</h3>
    </div>
    <h3 class="dts-fb-text">Some content here pt2..</h3>
    <div class="dts-fbn-bz1"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-bzh"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-ha"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dts-fb-hover"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="dts-fb3">
    <div class="dts-fb-trap">
      <h3 class="dts-fb-trap-title">Title3</h3>
    </div>
    <h3 class="dts-fb-text">Some content here pt3..</h3>
    <div class="dts-fbn-bz1"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-bzh"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-ha"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dts-fb-hover"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="dts-fb4">
    <div class="dts-fb-trap">
      <h3 class="dts-fb-trap-title">Title4</h3>
    </div>
    <h3 class="dts-fb-text">Some content here pt4..</h3>
    <div class="dts-fbw-bz1"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-bzh"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-ha"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dts-fb-hover"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is indeed a lot of repetition that can easily be removed, however, because the HTML and CSS are missing from your question, you will probably never get optimal Jquery code.

Comment: PLease click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57448333/edit), then `[<>]` snippet editor and add HTML and CSS to make a [mcve]. I am sure we can shorten everything - for example just add another common class to your elements with the poorly names classes

Comment: Thanks. I've added the shortened HTML and CSS as suggested.

Comment: I've tried to make [a JSFiddle with your JS/HTML/CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/ep8zhdbv/1/), but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry when stripping out uncessary code, I removed width and height elements for primary div. Here is a working model: https://jsfiddle.net/m6pdcge0/1/

Comment: I made you the snippet I suggested you could make. See how much easier it is to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding a hover class to all of the child elements on hover, you can add it once to the "main" element and use CSS to apply stuff to each child element.

```js
$('.dts-fb-hover').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('.dts-fb').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
#dts-fb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.dts-fb-trap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #000000;
}

.hover .dts-fb-trap {
  color: #bf0000;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #bcbcbc;
}

.dts-fb-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.hover .dts-fb-text {
  transform: scale(1.05) translateY(-50%);
}

.dts-fb-hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

.dts-fb-ha {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hover .dts-fb-ha {
  right: 10px;
}

.dts-fb {
  width: 500px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dts-fbw-bz1,
.dts-fbn-bz1 {
  background-color: #202020;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hover .dts-fbw-bz1,
.hover .dts-fbn-bz1 {
  background-color: #909090;
}

.hover .dts-fb-bzh {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #404040;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dts-fb">
  <div class="dts-fb">
    <div class="dts-fb-trap"> Title </div>
    <h3 class="dts-fb-text">Some content here..</h3>
    <div class="dts-fbw-bz1"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-bzh"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-ha"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dts-fb-hover"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="dts-fb">
    <div class="dts-fb-trap">
      <h3 class="dts-fb-trap-title">Title2</h3>
    </div>
    <h3 class="dts-fb-text">Some content here pt2..</h3>
    <div class="dts-fbn-bz1"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-bzh"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-ha"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dts-fb-hover"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="dts-fb">
    <div class="dts-fb-trap">
      <h3 class="dts-fb-trap-title">Title3</h3>
    </div>
    <h3 class="dts-fb-text">Some content here pt3..</h3>
    <div class="dts-fbn-bz1"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-bzh"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-ha"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dts-fb-hover"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="dts-fb">
    <div class="dts-fb-trap">
      <h3 class="dts-fb-trap-title">Title4</h3>
    </div>
    <h3 class="dts-fb-text">Some content here pt4..</h3>
    <div class="dts-fbw-bz1"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-bzh"></div>
    <div class="dts-fb-ha"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dts-fb-hover"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great too. Marked this as correct answer as this shortens the js more than other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the DOM to find the parent `div` and then use that parent to find the elements you wish to style.

Adding an class not a child of said parent is ok, so you can search for both `.dts-fbw-bz1` and `.dts-fbn-bz1` if one isn't found it will be skipped over, no error will be thrown.

```
$('.dts-fb-hover').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent('a').parent('div').find('.dts-fb-bzh,.dts-fb-text,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbw-bz1,.dts-fbn-bz1').addClass('hover');
}, function(){
    $(this).parent('a').parent('div').find('.dts-fb-bzh,.dts-fb-text,.dts-fb-ha,.dts-fb-trap,.dts-fbw-bz1,.dts-fbn-bz1').removeClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Ah thanks man. Worked like a dream. Needed to add some more classes but works great in the end. Thanks a ton. :)